# Making one variable dependent on another

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, csv

I've got small CSV file with data. I want all variables in a row to be dependent.

Assume I have got values 1, 2, 3 in the first row,
and 4, 5, 6 in second.

I have also three objects: objA, objB, objC.

I want to set values the of these objects depending on the values of another. So when the user sets objA's value as 1, I want objB and objC to take values of 2 and 3. But when user sets objC to value 6 I want objA and objB to take values of 4 and 5.

What's the best way to archieve this? It's an iOS project.

Comment: "How to design a spreadsheet engine?" sounds way outside the scope of a SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Key-Value-Observing
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/

Example:

```
[b addObserver:a forKeyPath:@"variableName" options:0 context:nil]; <--- object a observes changes in object b

// Some change
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
// Handle change
}
```